# Getting simple JAX-RS/CXF POST example to work

Tags: post, cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to get a simple CXF Rest webservice to work with POST. The webservice interface is as follows :

```
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@POST
@Path("/postExample")   
public Info postExample(String id);
```

I have tried  @Consumes with "text/plain" as well.
   Now I call the webservice from Flash AS3 as follows :

```
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:8080/XXXX/postExample");
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.id= abc;
request.data = variables;   
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.requestHeaders.push(header);
try {
    loader.load(request);
} catch (error:Error) {
    trace("Unable to load requested document.");
}
```

I expect that the webservice should receive the String "abc" , however it receives a String "id=abc" . Can someone help me understand what's going wrong here?

Regards,
JS

PS: Got it to work. Updated webservice interface to
  public Info postExample(@FormParam("id)String id));